# Can't create pivot table

Tags: pivot

I am having trouble with creating a pivot table with my code, it had worked on previous worksheets. Not sure if it is a data problem or my code.

My current code: area of concern is Create Pivot table using pivot cache

Sub CreatePivotTable()
' Set a reference to the active sheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = ActiveSheet

```
' Create a new worksheet for the PivotTable
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Set wsPivot = Worksheets.Add

' Name the new worksheet as "PivotTable"
wsPivot.Name = "Pivot"

' Define the data range (entire active sheet)
Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = wsData.UsedRange

' Create a PivotTable on the new worksheet
Dim pivotCache As pivotCache
Dim pivotTable As pivotTable

' Create a PivotCache using the data range
Set pivotCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange)
```

' Create a PivotTable using the PivotCache
Set pivotTable = pivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsPivot.Range("A3"), TableName:="Pivot")

```
' Set the PivotTable fields
With pivotTable.PivotFields("Product #")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With

With pivotTable.PivotFields("Product Description")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With

With pivotTable.PivotFields("DA")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .Position = 1
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00" ' Adjust the number format as needed
End With

' Set PivotTable options
pivotTable.DisplayFieldCaptions = False ' Hide field captions
pivotTable.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow ' Set to tabular form

' Delete rows 1 and 2
wsPivot.Rows("1:2").Delete

' Insert "RMB" in D2 and "VAr" in E2
wsPivot.Range("D2").Value = "RMB"
wsPivot.Range("E2").Value = "VAr"

' Filter D2 & E2
wsPivot.Range("D2:E2").AutoFilter

 ' Insert formula in E3 to calculate the difference between values in columns C and D
wsPivot.Range("E3").Formula = "=C3-D3"

' Fill the formula down to the bottom of the column
wsPivot.Range("E3").AutoFill Destination:=wsPivot.Range("E3:E" & wsPivot.Cells(wsPivot.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

' Insert formula in D3 to sumifs
wsPivot.Range("D3").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Work2!E:E, Work2!K:K, A3)"

' Fill the formula down to the bottom of the column except for the last cell
wsPivot.Range("D3").AutoFill Destination:=wsPivot.Range("D3:D" & wsPivot.Cells(wsPivot.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 1)

' Insert formula in the last cell of column D to sum all values in Work2!E:E
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wsPivot.Cells(wsPivot.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
wsPivot.Cells(lastRow, "D").Formula = "=SUM(Work2!E:E)"

' Activate the new worksheet
wsPivot.Activate
```

End Sub